# RBS optional block handling

Tags: ruby, types, rbs, steep

I'm trying to add RBS information to a ruby gem and am wondering if there is a way to make this work. Take this code:

```
def some_method(&block)
   if block
      foo = block.call
   end
end
```

and this signature:

```
def some_method: () ?{ () -> String } -> void
```

When I run it through `steep check` I get an error message like this:

```
[error] Type `nil` does not have method `call`
│ Diagnostic ID: Ruby::NoMethod
│
└           foo = block.call
                       ~~~~
```

Is there a good way to resolve this? I need `&block` to be optional, and at that point in the code I already know `block` can't be nil, but I don't know how tell RBS about that.

EDIT:
I know I could just change the code to be `foo = block&.call` but ideally I'd like to be able to keep the code the same.

Comment: I am having trouble recreating this issue with ruby 3.1.2,  rbs 3.4.3 and steep 1.6.0 [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/PointedImpossibleDevice#rbs/test.rbs). Can you provide some more context including rbs and steep versions?

Comment: @engineersmnky: Agreed. This should be handled by even the most trivial flow-sensitive type checker, which I believe Steep is. (Flow-sensitive, that is, not trivial.)